# Ember communicate between view components and controllers

Tags: ember.js

I have a dashboard and inside it some buttons for filter to `posts`.

This dashboard appear in all pages, so I a create a view `dashboard` with a template of same name.

to trigger filter, I have created an view `filter-button`:

```
export default Ember.View.extend(Ember.TargetActionSupport, {
  tagName: 'button',
  click(event) {
    this._toggleComponentState();
    this._dispatchAction();
  },
  _dispatchAction() {
    this.triggerAction({
      action: "filter",
      target: this.get('controller'),
      actionContext: this.get('context')
    });
  },
  _toggleComponentState() {
    this.$().toggleClass('active');
  }
});
```

this action `filter` this sent to `application controller`, but I need send to an specific controller `posts.index`, hierarchically posts and dashboard have no connection. how can I create a communication correctly between my components?

Comment: why you are using views , try component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trigger an action from controller A to controller B, you need to have B in A's `needs`. Then you can do `this.get('controllers.b').send('someAction')`.

Example code:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['foo'],

  actions: {
    lolAction: function() {
      var fooCtrl = this.get('controllers.foo');
      fooCtrl.send('anotherLolAction');
    }
  }
});
```

Demo: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tevagu/1/edit?html,js,output

But as @sushant said, stop using controllers and views.

Use controllers and views for only top level on each route. E. g. any route will have one controller, one view and one template and (and you don't have to explicitly define them all).

For content nested in routes' templates, don't use controllers and views. Use components instead.